# Synchronized copying display with jProgressBar

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, copy, jprogressbar

I wanted to monitor the progress of my file getting copied from source to destination. I have used `synchronized` keyword but somehow it not working as i expect it to be, my logic might be wrong. I will be glad if you help me out.
Here is my Code.

```
public class Download extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    int val=0;
    private Timer t;
    private ActionListener a;

/* Creates new form Download */
    public Download() {
       initComponents();
       jProgressBar1.setValue(val);
       a = new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (jProgressBar1.getValue() < val)
                jProgressBar1.setValue(jProgressBar1.getValue()+1);
            else
                t.stop();
          }        
       };
    }  
    public synchronized void copy(String source,String url)
    {
      try {    
        val+=25;
        t=new Timer(200,a);
        t.start();
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(source);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(url);
        int b;
        while ((b = fs.read()) != -1) {
           os.write(b);
        }
        os.close();
        fs.close();
      } catch (Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
      }        
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
      String url = null;
      int returnValue = chooser.showDialog(null, "Select");
      if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
         url = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
      } else {
         dispose();
      }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Wait for Completion");  

      if(CB1.isSelected()==true)
      {
        File f = new File(getClass().getResource("/PCycle/Ele.pdf").getFile());
        String source= f.getAbsolutePath(); 
        copy(source,(url+"\\"+CB1.getText()+".pdf"));
      }
      if(CB2.isSelected()==true)
      {
        File f = new File(getClass().getResource("/PCycle/Mech.pdf").getFile());
        String source= f.getAbsolutePath();  
        copy(source,(url+"\\"+CB2.getText()+".pdf"));
      }
      if(CB3.isSelected()==true)
      {
        File f = new File(getClass().getResource("/PCycle/Phy.pdf").getFile());
        String source= f.getAbsolutePath();  
        copy(source,(url+"\\"+CB3.getText()+".pdf"));
      }
      if(CB4.isSelected()==true)
      {
        File f = new File(getClass().getResource("/PCycle/Civil.pdf").getFile());
        String source= f.getAbsolutePath();  
        copy(source,(url+"\\"+CB4.getText()+".pdf"));
      }

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Completed");

      try {
            jProgressBar1.setValue(100);                
            Thread.sleep(3000);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Download.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Here I tried to implement a logic in such a that, whenever we call "copy" method it will copy the file from one location to another and before that it should run the timer method by which the progress on the `jProgressBar` is displayed.  But unfortunately even after using `synchronized` it is not displaying the progress for each file.

Comment: You may want to use [ProgressMonitorInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html), which automatically opens a Progress Monitor during reading from a stream, if the process takes a non-trivial amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are blocking Swing's Event Dispatching Thread (EDT).

Swing does all drawing when the EDT is not busy responding to events.  In this case `jButton1ActionPerformed` is not returning until all files have been copied.  So although a `Timer` is started during each `copy()` call, the timers never get a chance to expire, because `jButton1ActionPerformed` has never returned.

In this case, you want to use a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to copy the files in a background thread.

- When you want to start copying the files:

  - start the timer in the main thread
  - create and start the `SwingWorker`.
  - open a model dialog to block further user actions (or otherwise disable the UI)
- As the timer expires, your progress bar will advance, and be drawn.
- When the `SwingWorker` is `done()` (which is executed on the EDT),

  - stop the timer
  - dismiss the dialog (or re-enable the UI)

**Note**: Do not create or access any UI items, or create/start/stop timers, from the background worker thread.  These actions must only be performed on the EDT.

---

Rough example, showing disabling UI element, starting `SwingWorker`, publishing from the worker to show progress (which file is being download), enabling UI when the worker finishes.

File copy is faked using a 3 seconds sleep.

```
package progress;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Download extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Download::new);
    }

    private final JButton downloadBtn = new JButton("Start Download");
    private final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    private final Timer timer = new Timer(200, this::timerTick);

    Download() {
        super("Download Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        downloadBtn.addActionListener(this::startDownload);
        add(downloadBtn, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        add(progressBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void startDownload(ActionEvent evt) {
        downloadBtn.setEnabled(false);
        timer.start();
        DownloadWorker worker = new DownloadWorker("File1", "FileB", "AnotherFile");
        worker.execute();
    }

    private void timerTick(ActionEvent evt) {
        progressBar.setValue(progressBar.getValue()+2);
    }

    private class DownloadWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

        private final String[] files;

        DownloadWorker(String ...files) {
            this.files = files;

            progressBar.setValue(0);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for(String file : files) {
                publish(file);

                // Copy the file
                Thread.sleep(3000);  // Pretend copy takes a few seconds
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            String file = chunks.get(chunks.size()-1);  // Just last published filename
            progressBar.setString("Downloading "+file + " ...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            progressBar.setString("Complete");
            progressBar.setValue(100);
            timer.stop();
            downloadBtn.setEnabled(true);   // Re-enable UI
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir.
It will be more helpful if you can provide an example sooner.

Comment: Example added.  Hope you can adapt it for your needs.  Progress bar is just advancing by a fixed amount per timer tick, like you attempted to code in your problem sample code.  Ideally, you could query the worker for the number of bytes copied, compute a real progress percentage, etc.

Comment: Thank you sir, i adapted the changes and it really helped me.